# How to display Alert/Toast While my Response is NULL

Tags: android

The Parameter result can be null means i want to display Alert/Toast how can i do this, because my App going to be crashed when the Response is NULL.Here we go what i have thy this means.I think NULL value problem so i want to avoid this thing (crashed)

```
private class BackTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    ArrayList<String> list;
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        list=new ArrayList<>();
    }
    protected Void doInBackground(Void...params){
        InputStream is=null;
        String result="";
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost= new HttpPost("http://IP/web/getOrderPendCusname.php");
            HttpResponse response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            // Get our response as a String.
            is = entity.getContent();
            System.out.println(is);
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //convert response to string
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"utf-8"));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result+=line;
            }
            is.close();
            //result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // parse json data
        try{
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jArray = object.getJSONArray("Cus_name");
            //JSONArray jArray =new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                // add interviewee name to arraylist
                list.add(jsonObject.getString("Cus_name"));
            }
        }
        catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        listItems.addAll(list);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

LOGCAT:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject
07-21 17:01:16.057 17179-17289/com.example.vari.new_varri W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
07-21 17:01:16.057 17179-17289/com.example.vari.new_varri W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
07-21 17:01:16.057 17179-17289/com.example.vari.new_varri W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
07-21 17:01:16.057 17179-17289/com.example.vari.new_varri W/System.err:     at com.example.vari.new_varri.Order_Pending$BackTask.doInBackground(Order_Pending.java:579)
07-21 17:01:16.058 17179-17289/com.example.vari.new_varri W/System.err:     at com.example.vari.new_varri.Order_Pending$BackTask.doInBackground(Order_Pending.java:538)
07-21 17:01:16.058 17179-17289/com.example.vari.new_varri W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
07-21 17:01:16.058 17179-17289/com.example.vari.new_varri W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-21 17:01:16.058 17179-17289/com.example.vari.new_varri W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
07-21 17:01:16.058 17179-17289/com.example.vari.new_varri W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
07-21 17:01:16.058 17179-17289/com.example.vari.new_varri W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
07-21 17:01:16.058 17179-17289/com.example.vari.new_varri W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Can you post the complete method and the code where you call the method? Also please provide your logcat output with the crashlog.

Comment: you may missed `.show()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
 if(ReceivedVal == null)
 {
   Toast.makeText(context, "Null value Received..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   Log.i("NULL" , "Null value received");
 }
```

**EDIT 1 :**

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Null value Received..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

**EDIT 2**

Your `result` variable is String so you can check with `equals()` as,

```
if(result.equals(""))
{
 // your toast is here
}
else
{
  // do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: Check Log is printed or not

Comment: Can i change 'context' to my file name?

Comment: YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME.this

Comment: if(result == null)
                {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Toast.makeText(Order_Pending.this, "Null value Received..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }else {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
                    JSONArray jArray = object.getJSONArray("Cus_name");

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: i think can i check like this if(result == null)

Comment: then you can put Toast in catch

Comment: No bcz it will crash my app when open activity bro

Comment: did you check with Log??

Answer (score 1):

You really could have find this on google.

```
if(IDontKnowWhatValue == null){
    Toast.makeText(context, "MyMessage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: yes i tried inside of Try block but no Success E.g if(result == null){ Toast goes here..} else{JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jArray = object.getJSONArray("Cus_name");}